# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n^{a}\log(9/4)+((-1)^{n}-1)({3}^{1/n}-2^{1/n})$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n^{a}\log(9/4)+((-1)^{n}-1)({3}^{1/n}-2^{1/n})$$
>   converge or diverge?

I try to find the result: the series has the same nature as $$\sum{n^{a}\log(9/4)+\sum{((-1)^n-1)(3^{1/n}-2^{1/n})}}.$$ In the second series, I try to use asymptotic criterion but I am not able to conclude.

Comment: Are you sure the first logarithm is not $\log(3/2)$?

Comment: I' m sure, it is log(9/4)

Comment: In a way it is a pity: the exercice would be more interesting with $\log(3/2)$ instead of $\log(9/4)$ (or with $\frac12((-1)^n-1)$ instead of $(-1)^n-1$).

Comment: No, beacuse there is $((-1)^n-1)=-2$ when $n$ is odd. Therefore you find $log(9/4)$ in the second sum and you can collect.

Comment: As I tried to indicate, with $\log(3/2)$ instead of $\log(9/4)$, the series **converges**.

Comment: Why? Can you show me this?

Comment: The term $2n+1$ of the second part is equivalent to $-2\log(3/2)/(2n)=-\log(3/2)/n$. To compensate this by $c(2n-1)^a+c(2n)^a$, choose $c=\log(3/2)$ and $a=-1$. Then the sum of the terms $2n$ and $2n+1$ in the global series is $\ll1/n$ hence the series might converge (and in fact it does).

Comment: yes,this series with $c=log(3/2)$ becomes $\sum{\frac{(-1)^n*log(3/2)}n}$ and then this is leibniz series and converge. thanks

Comment: More care is needed because in alternating series one cannot rely on equivalents only but yes, this is the idea.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sum{n^{a}log(\frac{9}4)}+\sum{((-1)^n-1)(3^{1/n}-2^{1/n})}$

We note that our series has definitely constant sign for all $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$

$-2(3^{1/n}-2^{1/n})=-[\frac{1}nlog(\frac{9}4)+\frac{1}{n^{2}}(log^{2}(3)-log^{2}(2))+o(\frac{1}{n^{2}})]$

Hence, let $c_n$ the general term of the initial series and $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$
$c_n$=$\begin{cases}
n^{a}log(9/4) & & n=2k \\ log(9/4)(n^a-\frac{1}n)-\frac{1}{n^{2}}(log^{2}(3)-log^{2}(2))+o(\frac{1}{n^{2}})] && n=2k+1
\end{cases}$

the sequence of the partial sum of even numbers converges for $a<-1$ and diverges for $a>= -1$.
The sequence of partial sums of odd numbers converges only for $a = -1$.
Therefore the initial series diverges for all $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$

We note that if we change $log(9/4)$ with $log(3/2)$, with $a=-1$ we have:

$\sum(\frac{log(3/2)}n+\frac{[(-1)^n-1]log(3/2)}n)=\sum(\frac{log(3/2)}n[1+(-1)^n-1]))=log(3/2)\sum\frac{(-1)^n}n=log(3/2)log(2)$

Answer (score 0):

The second piece diverges.  The exponents go as

$$3^{1/n} - 2^{1/n} \sim \frac{\log{3}}{n} - \frac{\log{2}}{n} = \frac{\log{(3/2)}}{n}$$

as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Meanwhile, the term $1-(-1)^n$ selects odd terms.  From the comparison test with the sum of the odd reciprocal integers, the series diverges.

That said, when $a=-1$, the asymptotic behavior of the terms is

$$\frac{\log{(3/2)}}{n}(2 + [(-1)^n-1])$$

which then selects only even terms which, by a similar comparison, diverges.